# Get RefSeq accession numbers with versions

Tags: r, bioconductor, biomart, refseq

Google searching for **NM_002084** gives the following result:

[NM_002084.4](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NM_002084)

This, I assume, is the latest version v4, hence the `.4` suffix.

Searching for previous versions I get the following results, along with notes saying it was updated or removed.

[NM_002084.3](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/89903006)

> This sequence has been updated. See current version.

[NM_002084.2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?val=NM_002084.2)

[NM_002084.1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?val=NM_002084.1)

> Record removed. This record was replaced or removed.

Using *biomaRt* I can get the latest(**?**) version as follows:

```
library("biomaRt")

# define db
ensembl <- useMart("ensembl", dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")

# get refseqs
getBM(attributes = c('refseq_mrna',
                     'chromosome_name',
                     'transcript_start',
                     'transcript_end',
                     'strand'),
      filters = c('refseq_mrna'),
      values = list(refseq_mrna = "NM_002084"),
      mart = ensembl)
#  refseq_mrna chromosome_name transcript_start transcript_end strand
#1   NM_002084               5        151020438      151028992      1
```

But querying for specific versions gives nothing:

```
getBM(attributes = c('refseq_mrna',
                     'chromosome_name',
                     'transcript_start',
                     'transcript_end',
                     'strand'),
      filters = c('refseq_mrna'),
      values = list(refseq_mrna = c("NM_002084.1", "NM_002084.2", "NM_002084.3", "NM_002084.4")),
      mart = ensembl)
# [1] refseq_mrna      chromosome_name  transcript_start transcript_end   strand          
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

**Question:** How can I get all versions (preferably using R)?

Comment: Can you please explain why it's important to get all versions? The most recent version is typically an update of the sequence to correct errors in previous versions.

Comment: @gringer True having the latest version should suffice, but I find it strange that it is *not possible* to get all versions automatically, when data is available online through manual search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible using `biomaRt`, nor using `AnnotationHub`.

I have two suggestions, neither of them very satisfactory. First, you can specify an Ensembl archive for `biomaRt`, for example:

```
mart72.hs <- useMart("ENSEMBL_MART_ENSEMBL", "hsapiens_gene_ensembl", 
                      host = "jun2013.archive.ensembl.org")
```

Of course, that requires that you have some idea of the date for each accession version and that the archives span that date - so not especially useful.

The other option is to access EUtils using *e.g.* `rentrez`, which does allow search by version number:

```
library(rentrez)
es <- entrez_search("nuccore", "NM_002084.1 NM_002084.2")
es$ids

[1] "4504104" "6006000"
```

So knowing the accession, you could simply append 1, 2, 3... to it, run the search and see if UIDs come back, then get them using `entrez_fetch`.

EDIT: here's a quick and dirty function which takes an accession as query, appends version = 1, fetches the ID, then increments the version and repeats until no more results are returned. It is not well-tested!

```
getVersions <- function(accession) {
  require(rentrez)
  ids <- character()
  version <- 1
  repeat({
    es <- entrez_search("nuccore", paste0(accession, ".", version))
    if(length(es$ids) == 0) {
      break
    }
    ids[version] <- es$ids
    version <- version + 1
  })
  ids
}
```

Example:

```
getVersions("NM_002084")
[1] "4504104"    "6006000"    "89903006"   "1048339180"
```

Comment: `rentrez` library looks like a good solution, could you please expand with code the last sentence?

Comment: Edited with some extra code.

Comment: Are the ID's returned GI numbers? If yes, then they are not going to be very useful.

Comment: Well, that depends on what you want to do with the versions. If you want chromosome and coordinates as in the original question: that's always going to be difficult with old versions from old builds. If you want to retrieve the RefSeq records to compare versions, then UIDs are just fine.